# Excel - Always enable axis titles

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

Whenever I am using excel, I have to manually click the checkbox for enabling axis titles. I use axis titles for all my graphs anyways, is there a method to always enable axis titles?

I am using Excel 2013

Comment: I think you can save your final layout as ‘default’, and future graphs will look that way. Not sure though.

Answer (score 0):

From this [link](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/work-more-efficiently-by-changing-excels-chart-defaults/):

1. With the chart selected, click the contextual Design tab.
2. In the Type group, click Save As Template.
3. Enter *DefaultYourChartType* as the chart template's name, and click Save.

Now we're ready to save this template as the default chart type, as follows:

1. Click the Insert tab and click the Charts group dialog launcher.
2. Click Templates in the left pane.
3. Select *DefaultYourChartType* and then click Set As Default Chart.
4. Click OK